# sharepoint online modern search - add link to external site

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, sharepoint-search, modern-pages

is there a way to add a link to an external site in sharepoint online modern search?
or is there a way for this link to be the first results at all time?

Understand that PnP Modern Search web part is one method, but due to some issue, we are unable to use that.

Can anyone share?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You cannot customize the search results behavior of default SharePoint online modern experience search. You will have to use the custom SPFx solution, either use PnP modern search web parts or create your own SPFx web parts.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Microsoft Search instead. You can allow Microsoft Search to index third party data via custom connectors. More information can be found in the link below:

[Microsoft Graph connectors overview for Microsoft Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/microsoftsearch/connectors-overview)